# How to pass stdout of command in system() to self stdin?

Tags: c, linux

Assuming I call something like:

```
system("ls -1"); // argument minus-one puts one item per line
```

...how would I capture this in calling process stdin?

From what I've read, system (in Linux) opens a bash-prompt and attempts to execute the command. This indicates the process calling system is parent. [Reading about parent process pid suggest this is always `1111`](https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line), but I can't find a definite source on this, just linux haxers saying "do this" with neither explanation nor source.

Reading some other sources one can pass data to arbitrary process pipe through [/proc/pid/fd/0](https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi)

Based on reading those, I would think that:

```
system("ls -1 > /proc/1111/fd/0");
```

...accomplishes this. But it looks like nothing I've done before and my sources for the deduction are not as formal as I'd like them to.

So, is this a portable way of passing output of system command to self stdin?

If not, how would I do it?

Comment: You might be looking for [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: Why do you want to pass it to stdin? What are you trying to do?

Comment: *Reading about parent process pid suggest this is always 1111* -- No, `1111` is the PPID in that example.

Comment: If your problem is Linux specific, have you tried looking at [`readdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), which is the correct way to read the names of files in a folder.

Comment: `system` neither runs bash nor does it open a prompt. It passes the specified command to `/bin/sh -c`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Ok, good to know. Does it matter for this particular question or example whether I call it PID or PPID?

Comment: @melpomene Ok. Shouldn't matter though?

Comment: @Andreas you shouldn't try to redirect output to the `proc` file system. There will almost always be a permission issue.

Comment: @Andreas you should rather use a `FIFO`.

Comment: @Andreas The point is that it's not always 1111.

Comment: Thank you all for comments and answers. It would seem the question need more background so I'll close and reopen having that included. In particular, my Linux and POSIX versions are butchered to fit in a legacy system, along with an equally ancient compiler. This disqualifies many of the libraries. Also, the actuall command I'm looking at is 'cpio', not 'ls'. Because 'cpio' is more foreign I used 'ls' to get more attention. Wrong kind I see.

Comment: @melpomene Any way to get it?

Comment: @Andreas Get what? Your own PID? Sure, but how would that help you? Why don't you just use `popen` as suggested by Bo Persson?

Comment: @melpomene Was hoping not to depend on linux specific binaries/headers since my system is so old, but popen looks harmless enough... gonna have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to read the list of all file/folder names in a particular directory. In your case the current working directory. It also appears you are interested in a *NIX solution since you tried to use `ls`.

There are many ways to read the output from a subprocess into the parent process. You can use `fork`/`exec` with pipes or you are use `popen`.

But for this example you need not go through `ls`. You are directly read the directory using the Linux API.

You need to use the functions [`opendir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`readdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir).

Consider the following program -

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    DIR *directory = opendir(".");
    if (directory == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    struct dirent * entry;
    while (entry = readdir(directory)) {
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
    closedir(directory);
    return 0;
}
```

You might want to skip the `"."` and `".."` entries if you don't want those.

Here is a [working demo](https://ideone.com/1GOaFl) for the same

Comment: You're missing an error check after `opendir` and you're checking `entry != NULL` twice for no reason.

Comment: @Melpomene I realized that I didn't error check `opendir`. But it's opening `"."`. I assumed it would always open. Anyway, I will improve the example a little.

Comment: `EMFILE` / `ENFILE` are always a possibility: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html#ERRORS

Comment: You can simplify your loop to `while ((entry = readdir(directory))) { printf("%s\n", entry->d_name); }`.

Comment: @Melpomene makes sense. Added error checking. Will also simplify the loop.

Comment: `-1` is not a valid return value from `main`. On Unix, you can only return values in the range 0 .. 255. In portable standard C your choices are between `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: @melpomene `ENOENT` is also possible.  The directory can be removed out from under the process.  And FWIW, I'm of the opinion that assignment inside a conditional clause is generally a bad idea - there's nothing gained from trying to cram as much code into as few lines as possible unless you're competing in the IOCCC.

Comment: Should have known I'd get answers specific for 'ls'... I'll change it soon but the command I'm really interested in is 'cpio'. AFAIK dirent does not provide that. Sorry, my bad on the misunderstanding

Comment: @Andreas The answer addresses the general case: "*There are many ways to read the output from a subprocess into the parent process. You can use `fork`/`exec` with pipes or you are use `popen`.*"

Comment: @Andreas whatever be the command, there has to be a programmatic way to access it. In the end the binary for the command will also use some OS api. You should try to look for that. If at all there is no documented standard way, you can use `popen`

Comment: turns out `popen` is available on the intended target platform. accepting answer.